# Display status of API call React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to React and TypeScript. I have the following code to call a Graph API (POST). Here is my code:

```
 export const OwnerPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    
      const [TextFieldValue, setTextFieldValue] = React.useState('');
      const [owner, setOwner] = useState([]);
      const [err, setError] = useState({});
    
      const onClick = () => {    
          callMsGraph(TextFieldValue)
            .then(response => setOwner(response))
            .catch(err => setError(err)); 
      } 
    
      const stackStyles: Partial<IStackStyles> = { root: { height: 44 } };
      return (
        <div>         
          <DefaultButton onClick={onClick}>{TextFieldValue}</DefaultButton>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Depending on the response from the API, I need to display some messages - Success message/Failure message. How would I do that?

API call:

```
export async function callMsGraph(groupId: string) {
    
    const headers = new Headers();
    

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify()
    };
    
    var url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/owners/$ref/`;
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => error);
}
```

Depending on the response from the API, I need to display some messages - Success message/Failure message.

For example, here the status code from the api call is 204 No Content. In this case, display 'Success'
[image]

Here the status code from the api call is 400 Bad Request with a message. In this case, display 'Failure' with the error message.
[image]

[image]

How do I update my code?

Comment: You've assigned the JSON from the API call to `owner`. If you know what's in `owner`, you can just access the properties like so: `owner.<property>`. If you're worried about the `fetch` request giving something that's not JSON or a different status code, you'll want to modify the logic of your code to handle the raw response and only convert it to JSON and `setOwner` if everything looks good. If you're worried about the `fetch` request having an error, you'll want to remove `.catch(error => error)` as that will prevent you from accessing the error later.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me where you're stuck.  It looks like you're putting the result of the operation into the `owner` state.  You can then use the value in that state however you like, such as conditionally rendering different markup based on the value(s) in `owner`.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can answer the question adequately with the current information, but I'll try.

### Why are you using `fetch` against Microsoft Graph API

There is already a client library for handling Microsoft Graph API requests, so I'm not sure why you're using fetch requests. The library is `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`.

### Using `fetch` requests in React

If you're sure that you can't use a library like `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`
or at least a fetching library designed for React like `react-query`, handling a fetch request is fairly universal. Warning: there are lots of different ways to use `fetch` in React and you should research the best solution for yourself; here I will be presenting only one solution.

#### Step 1: Initiating Fetch

The way you initiate your `fetch` request is important. Whether you're working with async functions or directly with the Promise methods, you'll want to set up your initial handling of the response and any possible errors. At the same time, you'll also likely want to save the fact that we're fetching and display that to the user.

```js
// save the fact that we're fetching
setStatus('fetching')

// async syntax
try {
  const response = await fetch(/* ... */)
  // data handling here
} catch (error) {
  // error handling here
}

// Promise API
fetch(/* ... */)
  .then(response => {
    // data handling here
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // error handling here
  })
```

#### Step 2: Determining how to handle the HTTP response by its status code

After you've initiated your fetch, we'll look at the data handling section. In there, we need to look at the HTTP response status code to see the result of our request. We can also look at the `ok` property to see whether or not the code is within 200-299, the successful responses range.

```js
if (!response.ok) {
  // handle unsuccessful response
  // you can throw an error if you want to handle unsuccsesful response logic in your catch statement
} else {
  // handle successful response
}

// or

if (response.status === /* specific code */) {
  // handle specific response type here
}
```

#### Step 3: Saving state

Once you've determined how to interpret the response, you need to save the interpretation in some manner so that you can display it later. In React, you can use `useState`, `useReducer`, or a state management library that integrates with React. My favorite option for this is XState's statechart library integration with React, `@xstate/react`.

```js
setData(await response.json())
setStatus('success')
```

The same goes for handling errors; you'll want to save your interpretation of the error so that you can display it to the user.

```js
setError(error)
setStatus('error')
```

#### Step 4: Displaying state

With this state saved, we now need to display it to the user. In React, it's very common to use ternaries in JSX to determine if something should be rendered or not. If you have more complex state or rendering logic, you can utilize if statements and switch statements.

#### Example

This example has not been tested and will likely need work to be useful to you, but here is an example of how you *could* start a fetch request, handle possible error states, interpret the response, save the state, and then display that state:

```
function useFetchMsGraph() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle') // idle, fetching, success, error
  
  return {
    data,
    error,
    status,
    async start(groupId) {
      if (status === 'fetching') throw new Error('Already fetching ms graph.')

      const options = {/* ... */}
      setStatus('fetching')
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/owners/$ref/`,
          options
        )

        if (!response.ok || response.status === 204 /* or something you're looking to handle */) {
          // You can add more logic here to handle expected response codes like 404 Not Found
          throw new Error(`Bad response code of ${response.status} while fetching ms graph.`)
        }
        const result = await response.json()
        setData(result)
        setStatus('success')
      } catch (error) {
        setStatus('error')
        setError(error.message)
      }
    }
  }
}

function OwnerPage() {
  const [groupId, setGroupId] = useState('')
  const msGraph = useFetchMsGraph()

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (groupId && msGraph.status === 'idle') msGraph.start()
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setGroupId(e.target.value)} value={groupId} />
      <button type="submit">Get Group Owner</button>
      {msGraph.status === 'fetching' ? <p>Loading...</p> : null}
      {msGraph.status === 'success' ? <p>Success! {JSON.stringify(msGraph.data)}</p> : null}
      {msGraph.status === 'error' ? <p>Failed, please try again!</p> : null}
    <form>
  )
}
```